# How to find pattern in string and cut out part that contains that pattern - C#

Tags: c#, string

I need to find pattern in my string and then cut out whole part that contains that pattern. I'll give an example what I need to do:

I have string like this:

```
string text = "Some random words here EK/34 54/56/75 AB/12/34/56/BA1590/A and more random stuff...";
```

In that string I want to check if this pattern exists:

```
string whatImLookinFor = "12/34/56/";
```

And If it is in my string so I want to cut out whole code that contains my pattern and it is separated with spaces:

```
AB/12/34/56/BA1590/A
```

Comment: Is whatImLookingFor fixed or does that change?

Comment: You are looking for _regular expressions_. Google for "c# regex". There are a lot of questions about that on SO. And to get an answer, you should make _really clear_ what you're pattern is: is it exactly "12/34/56/" or do you mean three groups of two digits separated by a slash? Or may there be letters too?

Comment: What if `whatImLookinFor` appears more than once in the string?

Comment: 'WhatImLookinFor' is not changing, but other can change i.e: 'BA1590/A' can change to 'BA5932/B'. 'WhatImLookinFor ' will not appear more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it using regular expressions or simply string operations.

This is using simple string operations:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "Some random words here EK/34 54/56/75 AB/12/34/56/BA1590/A and more random stuff...";
        var whatImLookinFor = "12/34/56/";

        // check if text contains it _at all_
        if (text.Contains(whatImLookinFor))
        {           
            // split the whole text at spaces as specified and retain those parts that 
            // contain your text
            var split = text.Split(' ').Where(t => t.Contains(whatImLookinFor)).ToList();

            // print all results to console
            foreach (var s in split)
                Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not found");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AB/12/34/56/BA1590/A
```

Comment: Your solution is so simple and that is exactly what I need! Huge thanks!